# Generating random sample with random.random in python

Tags: python, random

I'd like to generate a sample size of 100 random numbers between 0 and 1 using the random.random function.

```
import random
sample = [random.random for x in range(100)]
```

For instance, `while print(len(sample))` gives me 100, `print(sample[1])` returns just a reference to the random object() instead of the actual random number, which is what I want.

Why is this not working for me?

Probably basic, but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not calling the method:

```
[random.random() for x in range(100)]
              ^^
```

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce, no are not the first and won't be the last ;)